# ReactJS: How to signal a child component?

Tags: reactjs

For special testing purposes in a ReactJS app, I want to signal a child component like this:

1. User clicks a button on parent component A
2. A sends some kind of signal to child component B
3. B executes some logic in response to the signal

It's trivial to get B to communicate up to A, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to go the other direction. My first naive attempt was to pass a callback to B in props, but props are read-only, so that didn't work.  So before I go too deep hacking this, is there a clean, "blessed" way to do this?

Comment: Can you pls add your code into the question?

Answer (score 3):

That 'some kind of signal' is just state. State and props are the essential building blocks in React and most component communication is achieved using them. The parent to child relationship is usually more intuitive than child to parent - here is an example using functional components and hooks:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    const [signal, set] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentB signal={signal} />
            <button onClick={() => set(signal+1)}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        doSomethingWithSignal(props.signal);
    }, [props.signal]);

    return ...
}
```

Comment: Cool!  What is the equivalent of useEffect for a class?

Comment: For a class equivalent, you would want to use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and compare the previous `signal` with the next one.

Answer (score 0):

try

- React-context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
- Redux https://redux.js.org/
- You can pass your data or function by props from parent to children